# Odd Frame Rate 29.68 fps in Live Photos

Tags: macos, ios, photos, heic, h.265

***Why `29.68 fps`***?

Is it possible to set up a `30 fps` or `29.97 fps` frame rate for Live Photos?

The problem is a video part of Live Photos in iPhone X in iOS 11.3 uses quite strange variable frame rate – `29.68 fps`, that is not suitable for editing presets in FCP or DaVinci Resolve. If I convert Live Photos' frame rate to `30 fps` or even `25 fps`, a sound slightly or noticeably drifts away from sync at some point.

P.S. Live Photos in iPhone 7 (iOS 10) work with `29.97 fps`.

[image]

Comment: Blame the Americans. They invented drop-frame to compensate for their atrocious NTSC [Never Twice the Same Colour] television standard, so what ought to have been 30fps couldn't quite keep up.. Move to the light side & go with the European PAL standard, 25 fps. Solid. (yes, I'm joking, kind of ;-))

Comment: @Tetsujin NTSC's CFR 29.97 fps isn't the same as VFR 29.68 fps))

Comment: Just a question. Re your statement: *If I convert Live Photos' frame rate to 30 fps or even 25 fps, a sound slightly or noticeably drifts away from sync at some point*, can you clarify *how* you're converting the frame rate? In FCP? Something else? What settings?

Comment: @Monomeeth For instance, I set up my project in FCPX as Custom format 1440x1080, 30p, Render Sequence ProRes422, Audio 48kHz.
Then, I distribute 2 formats: H.264 30fps, audio 48kHz, and H.264 25fps audio 48kHz.

Comment: @Andy Hmm, considering that Live Photos are only 3 secs long, I wonder whether something else is at play here? Since Live Photos were first introduced the frame rate has varied between iPhone models (e.g. on an iPhone 8 it's **29.79 fps**). But this is just me thinking out aloud. If I get a chance I will try and replicate your issue. In doing so, are you joining multiple Live Photos together in your project, or...?

Comment: @Monomeeth Yes, I'm joining approximately 200 Live Photos and other video and audio together in a project. Sorry but I can't share this content because it's a property of my company. If you have any iPhone model with non-standard frame rate you can try it yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Andy - no worries, I definitely wouldn't want (or need) you to share any of the content. I just wanted to get a better context for what you were trying to do - I'm hoping to get the time to create a test project to see if I can replicate this behaviour and find a workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll try to answer my own question. I'm not sure this is 100% right.

I suppose frame rate's issue depends on the architecture of Live Photos itself. Total number of frames inside each Live Photo in iPhoneX is **85 frames** (look at the picture above):

```
42frames + 1frame + 42frames = 85frames
```

Frame rate for all these 85 frames is supposedly 30 fps, but considering just a video part (without a HEIC file), frame rate is 29.68 fps.

Here's a math:

```
//let's assume that 1/85th is 0.011764, 
//truncate that floating point number to 0.011
1 / 85 = 0.011

//let's assume that video frame rate of all 85 frames is 30 fps 
//so each frame's contribution is approximately 0.33 fps
30 fps * 0.011 = 0.33 fps

//thus H.265 video portion without HEIC frame will be 29.67 fps
30 fps - 0.33 fps = 29.67 fps
```

Value **29.67 fps** is very close to **29.68 fps**.

> **I reckon that altogether all 85 frames of Live Photos have frame rate 30 fps, but two H.265 video portions (without HEIC part) have frame rate 29.68 fps.**